# SQL Script: ORA-01790

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing a script that is used to extract three fields from our Powerschool database and spools the information into a .csv file.  This is the last in a series of six scripts that are basically identical except they are for different fields.  In all the other scripts, I have used the following to get a "header" row that corresponds with the .csv specifications from the vendor where the files will be going:

```
SELECT
    'school_id,student_id,email,first_name,last_name,Grade'
FROM
    Dual
UNION ALL
```

All five of the other files work flawlessly.  But, for some reason, this last one is generating error ORA-01790.  I cannot find the difference between this script and all the others.  What do you guys think?  Here is the full script generating the error:

```
set heading off
set pagesize 0
set linesize 400
set feedback off
set underline off
set trimspool on
SET LONGCHUNKSIZE 1024
SET LONG 10000
spool d:\psmajorclarity\csv\mcguardianexport.csv
SELECT
    'student_id,guardian_email,guardian_email2'
FROM
    Dual
UNION ALL
SELECT
  student_number || ',' ||
  guardianemail || ',' ||
  guardianemail
FROM students
WHERE Grade_Level>=6
AND Grade_level<=12;
SPOOL off
EXIT;
```

"Student_number" is datatype FLOAT and "guardianemail" is CLOB.

And here is one of the scripts that is fully functional and performs as expected:

```
set heading off
set pagesize 0
set linesize 400
set feedback off
set underline off
set trimspool on
SET LONGCHUNKSIZE 1024
SET LONG 10000
spool d:\psmajorclarity\csv\mcstudentexport.csv
SELECT
    'school_id,student_id,email,first_name,last_name,Grade'
FROM
    Dual
UNION ALL
SELECT
  schoolid || ',' ||
  student_number || ',' ||
  NULL || ',' ||
  first_name || ',' ||
  REPLACE(last_name,',') || ',' ||
  grade_level
FROM STUDENTS
WHERE Grade_Level>=6
AND Grade_level<=12;
SPOOL off
EXIT;
```

Comment: To quote yourself `This is the last in a series of six scripts that are basically identical except they are for different fields`... Check your data types for these different fields. Without your data we can't do much to help you.

Comment: Rup:  Your response was the fix.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have fixed my problem.

I changed this:

```
SELECT
        'student_id,guardian_email,guardian_email2'
    FROM
        Dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      student_number || ',' ||
      guardianemail || ',' ||
      guardianemail
```

To this:

```
SELECT
    'student_id,guardian_email,guardian_email2'
FROM
    Dual
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR
  (student_number || ',' ||
  guardianemail || ',' ||
  guardianemail)
```

That made the .CSV file generate normally.  I guess the email field being a CLOB made this necessary.

Comment: Makes sense to me, you are unioning the first set of rows for the header, which most likely are getting set as character fields.